# why use super : public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)

Tags: java, generics

why not use extends :

```
public TreeSet(Comparator<? extends E> comparator)
```

thank you !

search stackoverflow ,but not answer。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: the comparator needs to read elements (not *write*). Example, if you have a set of `Number`, a comparator for `Object` would work, but not a comparator for `Integer` (set could contain a `Double`)